# simple addition code with serious error-handling

Tags: c++, parameters, error-handling

I'm pretty new to c++ and am in the process of writing a simple addition program. So far I have this code, which only works with numbers for parameters:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc==1)
        cout << "email@gmail.com";

    if (argc==2)
        cout << "P";

        //addition function
        if (argc==3){

        float number1 = atof (argv[1]);
        float number2 = atof (argv[2]);

        cout << number1 + number2 << endl;
        }

    if (argc>3)
        cout << "P";

    return 0;

}
```

As you can see, I'm assigning argument values to variables and adding them. These argvs are what will be tested on, and they have to be able to handle everything. so I have a few problems:

-if one of the variables is not a valid number (like 1, or 3000), how do I get my program to pick up on this, and act on it? To be valid a number must also not be an equation (like a fraction or whatever) itself.

-if a strange valid number (like 3,000.2 (notice the comma)) is entered atof changes this to 3, how do i change this?

so yeah, throw some integrated error checking/handling techniques at me, and i'll forever love you.

Comment: Why are 1 or 3000 not valid numbers?

Comment: Most routines parsing strings to integers or float stop at the first non-digit it reads. That's why `3,000.2` is converted to `3`. Also, the command and dot have different meanings in different locales, e.g. for some `3,000` is three-thousand while for others it's three-point-zero.

Answer (score 0):

`atof` is not good enough to detect if a string represents a valid number (e.g. for "0.25lalala" it would return 0.25).

Full C++ solution:
First: include one additional headers:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Then in your `main` function:

```
    //addition function
    if(argc==3)
    {
            float number1 = 0.0;
            float number2 = 0.0;
            istringstream istr(argv[1]);
            istr >> number1;
            if(istr.rdstate() != ios::eofbit)
            {/* argv[1] is not a valid float number */
            /* it works even if undeflow or overflow occures */
            }
            istr.clear();
            istr.str(argv[2]);
            istr >> number2;
            if(istr.rdstate() != ios::eofbit)
            {/* argv[2] is not a valid float number */
            /* it works even if undeflow or overflow occures */
            }

            cout << number1 + number2 << endl;
    }
```

Comment: That is a definite improvement, but I'm also supposed to be able to use numbers like 4,000 (notice the comma), which are still outputted as 4. maybe i don't understand all that's used in this code yet.